# Django validate queryset None

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a queryset in order to check if the result is Null or exists

```
cupon_existente =  Orden.objects.filter(user = self.request.user, ordenado= False).values_list('promo', flat=True)
```

when the result is 'None' and I want to validate like this:

```
if cupon_existente:
   True
else:
   False
```

it validates as 'True'

how can I validate that None is actually 'False' or 'NULL' ?

Comment: try `Orden.objects.filter(...).exists()`. It returns True if the resultant queryset is not empty, else False

Comment: yes, at the end I had to do if cupon_existente is None:

Answer (score 0):

what I did to catch the None as empty or null was:

```
if cupon_existente is None:
   messages.warning(self.request, "Ya tiene un cupón aplicado")
   return redirect("pago-cupon")
```

I added the is None validation